# C#- Validation for US or Canadian zip code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using following method to validate US or Canadian zip code, but i think it is not working fine for me. Please suggest me the changes in the regular expression.

```
private bool IsUSorCanadianZipCode(string zipCode)
    {
        bool isValidUsOrCanadianZip = false;
        string pattern = @"^\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        return isValidUsOrCanadianZip = regex.IsMatch(zipCode);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any specific test cases that this method is failing on? By the way, you can declare the `Regex` as a member variable so that you don't construct it in every method call.

Comment: I'd add some parentheses around the patterns you are or-ing together.

Comment: By "valid" do you only mean "is in the correct format"? There are plenty of 5 digit numbers, and even more 5+4s, that aren't actually used as zip codes.

Comment: [US and Canada zip code validation RegEx](http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/12/03/117321.aspx)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
    var _usZipRegEx = @"^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$";
    var _caZipRegEx = @"^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$";

    private bool IsUSOrCanadianZipCode(string zipCode)
    {
        var validZipCode = true;
        if ((!Regex.Match(zipCode, _usZipRegEx).Success) && (!Regex.Match(zipCode, _caZipRegEx).Success))
        {
            validZipCode = false;
        }
        return validZipCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Data Annotation Validators, you can use a RegularExpression attribute like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXYabceghjklmnprstvxy]{1}\d{1}[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZabceghjklmnprstv‌​xy]{1} *\d{1}[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZabceghjklmnprstvxy]{1}\d{1}$)", ErrorMessage = "That postal code is not a valid US or Canadian postal code.")]
```

(regex is from the link @huMptyduMpty posted above at http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/12/03/117321.aspx but my regex allows both upper and lower case letters)

Comment: +1 for the data annotation, but -1 since it's not 100% valid. Per Wikipedia, 'Postal codes do not include the letters D, F, I, O, Q or U', yet I was able to enter any of these (although not as the first character). I.E I was able to enter G1Q 3i7 and it did not show a validation error.

Comment: If you're going to "-1" for not being 100% valid, you should also include a recommendation to fix the solution, since you seem to have found a weakness in the regex that the author of that blog didn't recognize.

Comment: Good point. I think if you take d moncada's Canada Regex but add lowercase letters, that would be a good solution.. something like `^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXYabceghjklmnprstvxy]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZabceghjklmnprstvxy])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZabceghjklmnprstvxy]\d)$` would work well (for Canada).

Comment: Thank you, @Paul. I have updated my answer with your changes. I am not personally very familiar with Canadian postal codes, so I assumed the author of the blog had it right. Looks like someone in the comments there also pointed out the weakness in the regex, but we've got it right here now in this answer. Cheers!

Comment: The upper and lowercase alpha characters don't match in the second two alpha sections of the regex. 'W' and 'Z' are accepted, but 'w' and 'z' are not.

Answer (score 0):

The US zipcode validation which works "on my machine" is

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{5}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip Code")]
```