# How do i make sure that the user inputs the right character type in C#?

Tags: c#

The task is to create a segment of code where the user has to put his postal code. It has to be "letter + number+ letter + space+ number + letter + number". It needs to have 7 characters max and use a "if" statement to verify and post an error if the user doesn't input the right type characters.For example : A2B 1C3

```
string postalCode;
Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Postal Code");
postalCode = Console.ReadLine();

if (postalCode.Length == 7)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your Postal Code is " + postalCode);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error invalid Postal Code");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Look into regular expressions.  You can create an expression which matches that sequence and test the input against that expression.

Comment: What's the exact question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#- Validation for US or Canadian zip code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942602/c-validation-for-us-or-canadian-zip-code)

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that you should use regular expressions. This can easily be solved using simple and readable code - no need to over complicate it.

Firstly, as you have already done, you can get the length of the string easily. If it is a valid length, then it is just a matter of checking that each character in the string is valid. You can use the [IsDigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IsLetter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx) methods from [char](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Char(v=vs.110).aspx) to check that any given character in the string is a number or a letter. You could write a method such as:

```
public bool IsValidPostcode(string postcode)
{
    return postcode.Length == 7
        && char.IsLetter(postcode[0]) 
        && char.IsLetter(postcode[2]) 
        && char.IsLetter(postcode[5])
        && char.IsDigit(postcode[1]) 
        && char.IsDigit(postcode[4]) 
        && char.IsDigit(postcode[6])
        && postcode[3] == ' ';
}
```

and use this in your example like:

```
if (IsValidPostcode(postalCode))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your Postal Code is " + postalCode);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error invalid Postal Code");
}
```

If you wanted to look into solving this through Regex, you can achieve the same effect through something like:

```
bool validPostCode = Regex.Match(postalCode, @"^[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z] \d[a-zA-Z]\d$").Success;
```

**EDIT**

If the constraints from IsDigit and IsLetter are not suitable, the OP could also build up a list of permissible characters themselves and check against it:

```
public static bool IsValidPostcode(string postcode)
{
    char[] validLetters = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1)
        .Concat(Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1))
        .Select(c => (char)c).ToArray();
    char[] validNumbers = Enumerable.Range('0', 10).Select(c => (char)c).ToArray();

    return postcode.Length == 7
        && validLetters.Contains(postcode[0])
        && validLetters.Contains(postcode[2])
        && validLetters.Contains(postcode[5])
        && validNumbers.Contains(postcode[1])
        && validNumbers.Contains(postcode[4])
        && validNumbers.Contains(postcode[6])
        && postcode[3] == ' ';
}
```

Obviously `validLetters` and `validNumbers` would be much more appropriate as constructed once class members, but I've placed them within the method for ease of illustration.

Comment: Note that `IsLetter` and `IsDigit` use Unicode character properties, which may not be what you want. Your code block is equivalent to the regex `^\p{L}\d\p{L} \d\p{L}\d$`. Asker probably wants `^\[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z] [0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]$`

Comment: Fair comment - see my edit for an equivalent solution if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, that should work, although I'd argue using a regex would be more *simple and readable* now :) If you absolutely want to do this through code it'd be easier to write two helper functions like `static bool IsAsciiLetter(this char c) => 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' || 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z';` - you get the point. Or by adding a condition like `postcode.All(c => c < 128)` to your first solution.