# Convert IsNumeric(textbox.Text) vb net code in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

few years ago I was made a project on vb net It was a code to validate if the value was zip code for United States or postal code for Canada. I want to do same thing with c#.

```vb
Private Sub txtCodePostal_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handle txtCodePostal.KeyDown
   IsNumeric(Me.txtPostalCode.Text) Then
```

Convert vb net code in c#

Comment: Is [C#- Validation for US or Canadian zip code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942602/c-validation-for-us-or-canadian-zip-code) of any use to you?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's good for validating the format, but doesn't ensure that it's still a valid postal/zip code for either country. OP it would be best to reach through an API to confirm this if possible.

Comment: @Trevor Agreed; I linked to it because it appeared to offer a zero-cost improvement over IsNumeric.

Comment: We have the [Zip-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code#ZIP+4) in the US, in the format 00000-0000, which !IsNumeric